# How to improve the performace of this react filter && search algorithm?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting

Currently working on a website with the following sorting function, but it's slow and reloads several times when I search for someone; how can I improve its performance? Or, more importantly, which parts of this function are slowing down the search?

```
 const getFilteredPeople = ({ people, searchQuery, isMatch }) => {
    let list = people;
    if (searchQuery.length > 0) {
      const searchTerm = searchQuery.trim().toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);
      list = people.filter((person) => isMatch(searchTerm, person));
    }
    if (list) {
      return list.sort((a, b) =>
        (a.knownAs || a.firstName).localeCompare(b.knownAs || b.firstName)
      );
    }
    return [];
  };
```

As for the arguments to that function where it's called:
people:

```
const people = useSelector((state) => state.people.items);
```

searchQuery:

***text input for person's name, added via useState hook***

isMatch:

```
  const isJobRoleMatch = (searchTerm, person) => {
    const personFrags = person.jobRole?.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);
    return searchTerm.every((searchWord) =>
      personFrags?.some((personJobRoleFragment) => personJobRoleFragment.includes(searchWord))
    );
  };
```

Comment: How are you applying/calling the filter? On every keystroke?

Comment: Yes. Searching for a part of someones name should return everyone with that part at the start of either of their names...

Comment: I'd recommend looking into throttling/debouncing the function instead of trying to optimize inside first. I'm sure there's some optimizations you could make but instead of firing the filter on every key, only do it once the user has stopped typing?

Comment: When you say it reloads are you saying the page actually refreshes, or that the code fetches data from an API, or something else? We probably need to see a [mcve] to properly diagnose the issue.

Comment: The page itself doesn't reload, the react component holding the 'people' items reloads with new data, several times during *and* after a search term is typed. Often more component reloads than characters typed. Data is being queried from aws dynamodb.